# Visual Studio 2017 Node.js Exceptions not working

Tags: node.js, debugging, exception, visual-studio-2017

I just started Node.js development with VS 2017 Professional. Debugging generally works but when a uncaught exception is thrown the nodejs process is stopping immediately an i have no change to track the issue. I have also enabled the nodejs exptions in the debugger settings, but still no success. How can i setup VS to show the exceptions like in the C# development?
Thanks!

Comment: Would you please share the latest information in your side? Is it related to the VS debugger settings or the project itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I test a simple sample using VS2017, it works well in my side even if I use the VS2017 Enterprise version.

(1) Please make sure that you use the latest VS2017 version. 15.7.3.

(2) Please make sure that you install the latest Node.js version.

https://nodejs.org/en/

(3) Enable the Exceptions settings like the following screen shot. And enable "Use the new Exception Helper" option under TOOLS->OPTIONS->Debugging.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Enabling JavaScript (Node.js 8+) Exceptions did the trick! Another short question: what would you as expert say should i work for node.js development with VS Code or Standard Visual Studio?