# NodeJS Output Not Showing In Visual Studio 2017

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to get started with NodeJS (8.12.0) in Visual Studio 2017 (15.8.4). My understanding is that Node's output is supposed to appear in the Visual Studio 2017 Output window (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49589521), but it is not. I also thought that in the case of an error/exception, Node's pop-up console should remain open until you dismiss it (http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/jumpstart-35-prevent-visual-studio-node-js-console-closing-immediately-after-execution/), but that also seems not to be the case: if I run code with an exception, the console pops up & immediately closes.

With no errors in the code I can force the console to stay open with something like:

```
setTimeout(function () { process.exit(); }, 5000);
```

...But obviously that's just a workaround, and it still doesn't work if there's actually an error.

Am I wrong in that Node should be outputting to VS's output window, and/or remaining open to allow me to read potential errors? I've googled & googled, but can't seem to figure out why neither of these are happening in my case, nor how to resolve them. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Visual Studio 2017 Node.js Exceptions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50778294/visual-studio-2017-node-js-exceptions-not-working)

Escpecially "Debug->Windows->Exceptions->Enabling JavaScript (Node.js 8+)" did the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately I long since abandoned Visual Studio for Node development, & moved over to VS Code (this question was from 17 month ago).  What's the proper protocol for accepting answers that I can't myself verify...?